# Monotonicity of $\int^x_0\frac{F(y)}{F(x)}dy$

Tags: probability-distributions, monotone-functions

Let $F$ be a continuous and strictly increasing CDF with support $[0,1]$.

Can we show that $\int^x_0\frac{F(y)}{F(x)}dy$ is increasing in $x$? Or can we find a CDF that we can use it as a counterexample?

I've tried some well-known CDF's with a finite support, but I had monotonicity with all of the CDF's.

Any tips or help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: No, your integral is not always increasing. Consider the following strictly increasing, continuous CDF:

\begin{align}
F:\Bbb R&\to[0,1] \\
x&\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
0, &x\le 0  \\
\frac{49}{10}x, & 0\le x \le \frac1{10} \\
\frac{39}{80}+\frac{x}{40}, & \frac1{10}\le x\le \frac9{10} \\
\frac{49}{10}x-\frac{39}{10}, & \frac9{10}\le x\le 1 \\
1, & 1\le x
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
Plot of $F$:
[image]

Then we have 
\begin{gather}
\int_0^{\frac9{10}} F = \frac{849}{2000}, \\
\int_0^1 F = \frac12,
\end{gather}
and thus 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac9{10}} F}{F\left(\frac9{10}\right)}=\frac{\frac{849}{2000}}{\frac12}=\frac{849}{1000}>\frac12=\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^{1} F}{F\left(1\right)}.
\end{equation}

Hence, $x\mapsto \dfrac{\int_0^x F}{F(x)}$ is not increasing (in fact, it decreases strictly on $]\frac9{10},1[$).

*Remark.* Since you can approximate any continuous function on $[0,1]$ arbitrary well (w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm) by smooth functions, it is also possible to construct a smooth counter-example.

Comment: Wow... great thanks for the very specific example!

Comment: @Andeanlll You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

*Thought I had an idea that might work; maybe someone else can see how to finish it.*

Let $G=F^{-1}$; then making the change of variables $y=G(t)$,
$$
\int_0^x \frac{F(y)}{F(x)} \,dy = \int_0^{F(x)} \frac{t}{F(x)} G'(t) \,dt.
$$
Since $w=F(x)$ is increasing, it suffices to determine whether
$$
\frac1w \int_0^w tG'(t) \,dt
$$
is an increasing function of $w$. Integrating by parts,
$$
\frac1w \int_0^w tG'(t) \,dt = \frac1w \bigg( tG(t)\bigg|_0^w - \int_0^w G(t)\,dt \bigg) = G(w) -\frac1w \int_0^w G(t)\,dt ...
$$

Comment: The last expression is the difference between a strictly increasing continuous function and its running mean. I feel like this should indeed be increasing.

Comment: Have a look at my counter-example (I hope I didn't screw it up this time )

Comment: Between $t=0$ and $t=1/2$, let $G$ be the linear interpolation of $0$ and $1$. Then the difference between $G$ and its running mean is decreasing for $t > 1/2$.

Comment: @user159517 My counter-example works basically like that (although yours is a little more elegant)